# Need guidance in appending child control to parent control without postback ( using Ajax )

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am developing a website, for questions and answers ( just plain text ), and so far I have done the backend and front end design.

Guys, I know there are lots of questions asking on this matter, However, I have achieved most part, as you can see in the screenshot. The screen shot is taken from the actual web page (except for the red ink) I have implemented using two nested repeaters and some css styling. The DB is also set up and the data is fetched, formatted and displayed so far.

I need to know how I can submit comments as demonstrated. There is a textarea and a submit button at the end of each question group , and this submit should load the content to the database and append the comment to the parent ,  ALL without a full POST BACK (page refresh).

P.S: Don't mind the silly text on it :D

Ready to accept anything you may have to offer. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this is what you meant. By post back i guess you mean you want to avoid a page reload. If so, you can do an AJAX POST to submit the comment. On its callback, you can append the item to the parent using javascript.

Comment: yes , i meant a full post back actually. Can you give an example on that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mention postbacks in ASP.NET, I'm assuming you are using web forms.

**UpdatePanels (ASP.NET AJAX)**

If you are trying to avoid a full postback, a judiciously-used `UpdatePanel` will be the quickest way to achieve that result with web forms in ASP.NET. By "judiciously-used", I mean:

- Viewstate is disabled or very, very small
- The total async POST size is < 2K (remember all form fields on the page will be submitted with an `UpdatePanel`), whether or not they are inside of it.
- The UpdateMode on the `UpdatePanel` is set to `Conditional`.
- There are a reasonable number (usually less than 10) `UpdatePanels` on the page. Every UpdatePanel on the page generates script and adds to the overhead of rendering the page.
- You are not doing anything too complex inside the `UpdatePanel`; a good example of "complex" are client-side script/plugins which get "confused" when the `innerHTML` of the panel is updated.

**jQuery/WCF Solution**

Alternatively, you can use the jQuery `ajax` method to send data back to the server in response to some event (such as clicking a button). This will require client-side code, and a server-side handler of some sort to process the incoming data, persist it to the database or your view model, etc.

Here is an abbreviated example of using jQuery's `ajax()` method.

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET|POST", // pick GET or POST
        url: "handler URL here",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {  }, // JSON object containing data
        success: function (data) {
            // fired upon success
        }
    });
```

WCF is an excellent choice for processing the incoming data. ASP.NET 4.0 has solid support for  JSON-based messaging and provides granular control over security to prevent unauthorized requests. A WCF endpoint can be ASP.NET session-aware.

Comment: thanks I know how to use that, but want to know if this is applicable in the scenario which I mentioned.

Comment: @ShaneAdrianMuaz - Both of the approaches I mentioned are valid for your situation, but I would go the jQuery route because it is lightweight and submitting comments back to the server probably doesn't require any of the ASP.NET page lifecycle functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're OK with using jQuery on your application.

Lets say the id of the button used for sending the message is 'sendBtn', the id of the textbox is 'chatTxt' - and all your chat messages are displayed inside a div with id 'chatContainer'.

For the AJAX-POST, your code will be something like:

```
$.post(
  "chat.php", // replace this with your server side script that saves chat messages
  { 
    text: $('#chatTxt').val()
  },
  function(data) { // this will be called once the server returns, lets say it returns OK on success
    if(data == "OK") {
      // code to append the item to the chatContainer
      // replace the appended HTML with the actual structure of each chat item in your app
      $('#chatContainer').append('<div class="chatitem">'+$('#chatTxt').val()+'</div>');
    }
  }
);
```